# Is there any way to install android app without having internet?

Tags: android

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Mini S, but I don't have 3g or wi-fi internet - I have internet only on my computer. Is there any way to install android apps without internet, via bluetooth or using the USB cable? (I do have bluetooth on my computer).

If it's possible to install the apps than where could I download the apps? The Market doesn't let me download them to my computer.

Comment: I'd say this belongs on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) since it's not programming related.

Comment: Cross-posted now: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/is-there-any-way-to-install-android-app-without-having-internet

Answer (score 2):

Yes, having the .apk file, you copy it to your phone and open it's from there, the "Package Manager" will open and ask you to install the program.

When it's done, your application was installed.

Also, there's not possible to download the .apk files from the Android Market. Since the .apk is a simple zip archive and there contains all the application structure (also the .class, making it vulnerable to decompile). You can find some APK files over ethernet, but there's distributed from the developer, not the market.

Comment: Thanks!!! You saved my life, but I have one more question: where could I download apps, or is there any way to download from https://market.android.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some apps and put them on your device's sdcard and install it from there, but in order to access the Android Market you're going to need some kind of connection.  My advice would be to find some place that has free WiFi and use it there.